# How to align horizontally an icon with css?

Tags: html, css

I have this html markup, I would like to center horizontally an icon I have in a sprite, it have 15 % for the icon anc 85% for the info-data class. I would like to align center the icon.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 mf-item">
<div class="ico icon-theme"></div>
<div class="info-data">Theme</div>
</div>

.mf-item {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 0;
    min-height: 30px;
}

.ico {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 15%;
}

.info-data {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0f8ccd;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 85%;
}

.icon-theme {
    background-position: 0 -90px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 23px;
}
```

Any help will be appreciate it!!!!
Thanks!

Comment: could you please reproduce the issue in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)..

Comment: I dont know how to attach the icon and the bootstrap css

Comment: bootstrap css can be linked by specifying the "external resources" in the fiddle.. and just give some url of the image from the net...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are missing your `float:left` styling. I would do it something like this

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mf-item {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 0;
    min-height: 30px;
    width:100%;
}

.ico {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 15%;
    float:left;    
}

.info-data {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0f8ccd;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 85%; 
    float:left;
}

.icon-theme {
    background-position: 0 -90px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 23px;
    display:block;
margin:0 auto;

    background-color:red; //your background image imaging
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 mf-item">
  <div class="ico"><span class="icon-theme"></span></div>
  <div class="info-data">Theme</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But is not align the red box to the 15% div :(

Comment: I have no idea what you exactly mean, but I updated my answer. Maybe you can be more clear about your problem.

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: Added `margin:0 auto;` to the class icon-theme. ;)

Comment: Be aware that I changed your html. I added a span tag into your div with the class ico.   `<div class="ico"><span class="icon-theme"></span></div>`

Comment: Oh didnt see it, let´s try with that.

Comment: Yes it´s working thanks! I have to modify the html but thats ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`vertical-align: middle;`
that usually does the trick!